# Show model property if model exists and some string if not

Tags: django, django-templates

To make it clear I want do the following with just one line:

```
 {%if model %}
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" value="{{model.title}}" placeholder="Enter Title">
 {% else %}
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" value="" placeholder="Enter Title">
 {% endif %}
```

I tried this:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" value="{% model.title if model else "" %}" >
```

And it didn't work:

> Invalid block tag on line 15

I don't think I have to make a custom template tag for this simple kinda things.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" value="{%if model %} {{ model.title }}{% endif %}" placeholder="Enter Title">
```

Comment: One voteups and Thank You, But I think there should be a better way like this : {% model?model.title:"--" %}

Comment: And even better : {% model.title??"--" %}